# LINQ TO XML attribute tag give no object reference error

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Hi i am doing as follow

```
 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"F:\test2.xml");
        var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("autoivr.ok")
                where c.Element("LS_CZIP4").Value == "1234"
                select new
                {
                    name = c.Element("LS_LIN").Value,
                    state = c.Element("LS_STATE").Value                        
                };
```

When i use 
    where c.attribute("LS_CZIP4").Value == "1234"
i get error of object reference not set but when i use c.element there is no such error.

Following is the xml i made which is actually a table in sql converted to xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
   <autoivr.ok>
      <LS_LIN>abc</LS_LIN>
      <LS_STATE>def</LS_STATE>
      <LS_TYPE>5</LS_TYPE>
      <LS_CZIP4>1234</LS_CZIP4>
   <priority>0</priority>
   </autoivr.ok>
```

Can someone let me know the problem and how can i resolve and can i work with element tag only instead of attribute . Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use casting instead of accessing `Value` property. Casting to string will return null for non-existing elements. Getting `Value` will throw an exception

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"F:\test2.xml");
var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("autoivr.ok")
        where (string)c.Element("LS_CZIP4") == "1234"
        select new
        {
            name = (string)c.Element("LS_LIN"),
            state = (string)c.Element("LS_STATE")
        };
```

BTW you need closing tag for `<DocumentElement>`. Also `LS_CZIP4` is element, not attribute. See the difference here [XML Elements vs. Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp).

Element: `<LS_LIN>abc</LS_LIN>`

Attribute: `<autoivr.ok LS_LIN="abc">`

Comment: Can you explain how LS_CZIP is element and not attribute here and is it ok to work with elements instead of attributes if we have to query the xml file

Comment: @ffayyaz I've added example of LS_LIN as attribute and element. You should query for attribute if your item is an attribute in xml. If item is element, than query for element. Build your query based on xml structure.

Comment: thanks so my xml structure is fine as i have a table named autoivr.ok and table has multiple columns and rows so every column in table is being represented as an element in xml file and so on .

Comment: @ffayyaz actually I'd go with `autroivrs` as root element, with `autoivr` child elements for each row. But your current xml structure also will work.

Comment: something like 
    <autoivrs>
    <autoivr.fed_leg>
     elements
    </autoivr.fed_leg>
    <autoivr.fed_leg>
     elements
    </autoivr.fed_leg>
     </autoivrs>

Comment: @ffayyaz exactly, this name better describes that you have a collection of `<autoivr>` elements